# ImportError: cannot import name 'Accounts' from 'brownie.network.account'

Tags: nft, import, brownie

**Setup**

- MacOS Catalina v10.15.6
- IntelliJ Ultimate v2020.1.1
- Python v3.7
- eth-brownie v1.14.6
- Ganache CLI v6.12.2

I created a VENV using my Python 3.7.
Following [Patricks tutorial](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/nft-mix), I have installed eth-brownie and Ganache CLI, and now I am trying to create a simple NFT.

Executing (from the command line) the below works fine:

```
brownie run scripts/simple_collectible/deploy_simple.py --network rinkeby
brownie run scripts/simple_collectible/create_collectible.py --network rinkeby
```

However, I would like to create my own NFT from scratch. For this, I tried `brownie init` within a new project, but init always fails with the following error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Accounts' from 'brownie.network.account'
```

If I create a new Python file and add the following import, I get the same error:

```
from brownie import SimpleCollectible, accounts, network, config
```

I've tried everything I can think of - anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

i managed to solve this by uninstalling brownie and eth-brownie, and installing it again. Just run:

- pip uninstall eth-brownie
- pip uninstall brownie
  Check if they have uninstalled correctly doing a pip list, and then install them again:
- pip install brownie
- pip install eth-brownie

Hope it helps.