# Exception has occurred: ImportError x cannot import name 'accounts' from 'brownie'

Tags: brownie

Setup:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.0
- Brownie v1.18.1
- Ganache CLI v6.12.2 (ganache-core 2.13.2)

I'm currently following [Patrick's solidity tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ).  I'm at about 4:39:00.  Here is my code and the error that is occurring:
[image: from brownie import accounts error]

Is there a problem with the file **init**.py?

I've tried uninstalling and installing eth-brownie using the [directions here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101431/importerror-cannot-import-name-accounts-from-brownie-network-account).  However I'm still encountering this same error.

For reference the code I am trying to run is the following:

```
    from brownie import accounts

def deploy_simple_storage():
    #account = accounts[0]
    #print(account)
    account = accounts.load("freecodecamp-account")
    print(account)
print("Done with deploy_simple_storage()")

def main():
    print("Hello!")
    
print("Done with deploy.py")
```

And the error says "cannot import name 'accounts' from 'brownie'".

Thanks for the help.  Not sure what to do.

Comment: Alright, I was able to solve this by doing multiple things: pip uninstall eth-brownie, pip uninstall brownie, pip list (to check uninstalls worked), pip install brownie, pip install eth-brownie.... Then after all that I had to take out the "." from a file name so it wasn't in a file path.  After doing all that it was able to run like it was supposed to.

Comment: cc : Joseph Miyaki , you took out the "." from what file name?

Answer (score 0):

you're most likely getting this error because you only installed brownie-eth.
Uninstall brownie eth and then run

```
pipx install eth-brownie
```

when completed, run
`pip install brownie`

close your terminal and restart Vscode
this will work